# Trying to access beyond buffer length when decoding Solana program accounts data wit Borsh

Tags: web3.js, borsh

Going through the Solana Cookbook lesson 6 but got stuck:

If I try to decode the account data through Borsh, creating the data schema and using the decode function, I get:

**"Trying to access beyond buffer length"**

[image]

Here's the class I've created to handle serialization and deserialization:

```
    import * as borsh from "@project-serum/borsh"

export class Movie{
    title: string;
    rating: number;
    description: string;

    constructor(_title: string, _rating: number, _description:string){
        this.title = _title;
        this.rating = _rating;
        this.description = _description;
    }

    borshInstructionSchema = borsh.struct([
        borsh.u8('variant'),
        borsh.str('title'),
        borsh.u8('rating'),
        borsh.str('description')
    ])

    serialize(): Buffer {
        const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1000);
        this.borshInstructionSchema.encode({ ...this, variant: 0 }, buffer)
        return buffer.slice(0, this.borshInstructionSchema.getSpan(buffer))
    }

    static borshAccountSchema = borsh.struct([
        borsh.bool('initialized'),
        borsh.str('title'),
        borsh.u8('rating'),
        borsh.str('description'),
    ])
```

//finally, this is the deserialize function, responsible for deserializing data.

```
    static deserialize(buffer?: Buffer): Movie | null{
        if (!buffer) {
            console.log("no buffer")
            return null;
        }
        try {
            console.log("trying to decode")
            const { title, rating, description }=this.borshAccountSchema.decode(buffer) //the origin of my nightmares
            console.log(title)
            return new Movie(title, rating, description)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("DESERIALIZATION ERROR:: ", err)
            return null
        }        

    }
}
```

The doc says I could potentially decode it using borsh.deserialize(schema, class, buffer) - but it looks like deserialize() is not included in the TS JS implementation.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that the length of `description` is such that would take you beyond the end of the buffer, and that the buffer you’ve received has been truncated to cut off the end of the description?

Comment: please replace the screenshot of the error with a code block of the error text.  this will improve seo and help others find the question in the future

Comment: Hey, could you share the buffer you're trying to deserialize? I assume this is the course you're going through: https://soldev.app/course/deserialize-custom-data

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's gone over a year without a follow up.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been a long time without response of the author